# Build error when upgrading to SQLite for Universal Windows Platform v3.20.1

Tags: sqlite, uwp, c++-cx

In my UWP solution I have a C++/CX project which uses a SQLite database. I used the extension for Visual Studio 2015 called 'SQLite for Universal App Platform' to access SQLite db's. I decided to upgrade VS2015 Professional to VS2017 Community Edition. That went well and for some reason I decided to upgrade to the extension 'SQLite Universal Windows Platform v3.20.1' after uninstalling the old extension. Then I added the new extension in the reference manager.

When building the solution I got the error in the C++/CX project that the SDK 'SQLite.UWA.2015, Version 3.9.2' could not be found. This makes sense, so I changed all strings in the vcxproj file of the C++/CX project to 'SQLite.UWP.2015, Version 3.20.1'. Now I get the error:
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sqlite3.h': No such file or directory

I added manually the 'sqlite3.lib' to the Additional Dependencies, because that somehow got erased at some point in time. This however did not help.
Anyone an idea, what the problem might be or what to check?

Comment: You need to set the correct "include" directory -- use the `/I` switch or the property pages in VS - [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: With this version of the extension I had to explicit set the include directory with the path of the folder with sqlite3.h. This fixed the problem, but gave other build errors. Returning to the older version of the extension, C++/CX project referenced somehow automatically the sqlite3.lib file in the 'Additional Dependencies' and therefore I didn't have to set the include directory. Must be something in the extension I guess.